# Compare content of std::stringstream

Tags: c++, c++11, compare, stringstream

I have two `std::stringstream`: `ss1` and `ss2`, which are given as an argument to two different functions that fills them with data.

I want to sanity check that these functions writes the same content. How do I test for equality of two `std::stringstream`?

```
alg1.print(ss1);
alg2.print(ss2);

if(ss1 != ss2) {
   cout << "Content not identical!" << endl;
}
```

Does not work. Converting them both to `str()` works, however this seems ineffective. There must be a better way?

Comment: *Converting them both to str() works, however this seems ineffective.* Why is that? That is the only way to check whether the contents of the two streams are same.

Comment: You can examine the member functions for std::basic_stringstream at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream. There is no way to access the buffer without copying it out via str().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the only way to do so is to use the .str() method:

```
if (ss1.str() != ss2.str()) {
  cout << "Content not identical!" << endl;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is particulary fast but except if you are in an embedded context or you are checking millions of comparisons per second it should not matter.

Comment: You are probably right. The size of the content are in the order of 25 MiB, but as stated in the question, only used for sanity check. I guess that the copy part of `.str()` is quiet fast and cache efficient.

Answer (score 2):

There should be nothing wrong with using `str()` in this case.  If you're worried that the buffers will be very large, and `str()` will have a great deal of copy overhead, perhaps you could use the `>>` operator or one of the other member functions which allows you to extract smallers chunks of the stream, and perform the comparison incrementally.  Maybe you would prefer that to a single monolithic copy.